# How to authenticate google cloud function for HTTP trigger?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, http-authentication, jfrog-container-registry

I have a function app which is hosted in my GCP project with authentication turned on.
This app will be triggered from Jfrog container registry webhook based on events.

The issue I face here is to authenticate/authorize the HTTP request. I tried using "Authorization: bearer " header, which works good. But that token seems to expire after 60 minutes.

Q: Is there a permanent way(with no expiration) to authorize/authenticate cloud function HTTP requests ? Jfrog webhooks cannot programmatically create tokens since it's a simple HTTP POST trigger which can accept additional headers.

I am finding it hard to get a solution from GCP documentation. I do have the service account created with "roles/cloudfunctions.invoker" role.

Reference about Jfrog artifactory webhooks: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Webhooks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's for that reason I wrote that [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/secure-cloud-run-cloud-functions-and-app-engine-with-api-key-73c57bededd1). It's based on ESPv2 and Cloud Run, but [API Gateway](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway) is the managed version of that technical stack. The principle and the OpenAPI spec is the same.

The solution downgrade the security level from a short lived token (1h) to long lived token (no limit). But you can use API Gateway to ensure the API Key check and query forward.

A much more simpler pattern is to remove the authentication check on Cloud Functions (and make it public) and to perform that API key (in fact a random string comparison) in your functions itself.

---

In both case, the API is publicly accessible (API Gateway, or Cloud Functions) and, in case of DDoS attack, nothing will protect your service (and  your money). Set the correct Cloud Functions Max instance to prevent any bad surprise.

Comment: @guilaume - I'll try this option today. Thanks for guiding.

Comment: @guilaume - This works as expected ! Thanks for helping out. Your article has ESPv1 but now v2 is available. I tried with v2 and it works good. 
https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/set-up-cloud-functions-espv2#configure_esp